# Stacked TouchableOpacity inside another TouchableOpacity is not clickable

Tags: android, react-native, touchableopacity

Even though this document (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html) states, that touch events are passed down to the children and are only consumed by a parent, if the child doesn't react on the event, I face the issue, that a TouchableOpacity nested inside another TouchableOpacity doesn't react properly on touches.

My structure is like follows

```
<ScrollView>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('This is printed always')}>
    <View>
      <Text>I can click here</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('This is printed never')}>
        <Text>I can click here but the outer onPress is called instead of the inner one</text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
```

The same happens for Buttons inside TouchableOpacitys: Clicking the Buttons calls the onPress method of the parent TouchableOpacity

Am I overseeing something?

Comment: I ran into this issue when I was using a combination of TouchableOpacity from `react-native` and another one from `react-native-gesture-handler`. When using the same one twice it works as expected with the child being the only one to trigger the press event.

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock thanks ... I was having same issue as you mentioned.

Answer (score 45):

Change import of Touchable opacity from:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

to the following, and it will now all be fine:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I have the same imports from `react-native` but It didn't work.

Comment: I had to add `react-native-gesture-handler` dependency in the project because it is a peer dependency of `@react-navigation/stack`. this is causing pain for auto-import as `TouchableOpacity` is now in two dependencies...

Answer (score 7):

You could just use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` to wrap inner `TouchableOpacity`.

Something like:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('This is printed always')}>
    <View>
        <Text>I can click here</Text>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('This is printed never')}>
                <Text>I can click here but the outer onPress is called instead of the inner one</text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Why in the world does this work!?!?

Comment: Works for me,
can stack TouchableOpacity and TouchableWithoutFeedback

Answer (score 6):

Writing here to make it a little more prominent.

It could be the nested `TouchableOpacity` is being imported from something different from the parent one as mentioned by 
@EliezerSteinbock. This could be quite possible as many of us use auto-imports on visual code or other IDE.

Sadly I missed her comment the first time round, so hopefully this would help someone else

Comment: Bingo! ... damn `react-native-gesture-handler` :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (non-clickable nested touchable opacity) but with iOS only, and strangely it was fixed simply by rearranging the order of JSX elements within the parent container touchable opacity.

I had a nested absolute position touchable opacity declared first inside a container touchable opacity. Then, I had a flex-row view declared afterwards (also inside the parent container). I moved the JSX for the nested touchable opacity below the JSX for the flex-row view and it worked!

I had no idea that the ordering in JSX would matter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to always include code on your answer! [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This occurred because the `TouchableOpacity` was below the `View` in the component stack. The `View` was consuming the touch event before the inner `TouchableOpacity` had the chance to react to it. You could, alternatively, set a `zIndex` value in the style of the inner `TouchableOpacity` to fix the issue, without moving the order of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following (e.stopPropagation()) within the nested TouchableOpacity: Your code will look like such:

```
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.EmailContainer}
            onPress={() => setShow(!show)}>
            <Text>From</Text>
            <Text style={styles.Email}>
             {requestMoney?.email}
            </Text>
            {show && (
              <>
               <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                console.log(
                                                    'Selection one',
                                                );
                                            }}>
                                            <Text>Selection one</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>

                                        <TouchableOpacity
                                            onPress={(e) => {
                                                e.stopPropagation();
                                                console.log(
                                                    'Selection Two',
                                                );
                                            }}>
                                            <Text>Selection one</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </TouchableOpacity>
```